# Using AWS Swift SDK to upload image to S3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload an image to an S3 bucket using the putObject method in the AWS Swift SDK. I have followed the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html

I am able to add strings to the s3 bucket, but can't figure out how to add images.
I have tried converting the images to jpegdata and pngdata to no avail.

Here is my code:

```html
//      AWS S3 image upload
        func uploadFile(withImage image: UIImage) {
            let s3Client = try? S3Client(region: "us-west-2")

            let bucketName = "xxxxx"
            let imageData = image.pngData()
            guard let dataToUpload = "Text to upload working".data(using: .utf8) else {
                return
            }
            let body = ByteStream.from(data: imageData!)
            s3Client!.putObject(input: PutObjectInput(body: body, bucket: bucketName, contentType: "image/png", key: "Test")) { result in
                switch(result) {
                case .success(let response):
                    if let eTag = response.eTag {
                        print("Successfully uploaded the file with the etag: \(eTag)")
                    }
                case .failure(let err):
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }
```

If I place "dataToUpload" into the ByteStream.from function, the data gets stored in the s3 bucket. If I use the imagedata, however, it does not.

Open to any and all solutions,
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

you can also Use `AWSS3TransferUtility` to upload files to S3

**Steps**

1)Setup bucket credential  before uploading or simply  in your app delegate by this method `setupCreditial()`

2. upload file to s3 by using the `uploadFileToS3` method in your source view

   ```
     /** regionType is your bucket region name identityPoolId is your bucket unique id*/

    func setupCreditial(){


        let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .AFSouth1, identityPoolId: "YourPoolID")
        let config = AWSServiceConfiguration.init(region: .AFSouth1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)

        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = config
        AWSS3TransferUtility.register(with: config!, forKey: "NAMEOFUTILITY")
    }
    /*
     key is your aws3 key where you want to put image . in most cases it would public/key where key = any udid
     content type is is file type like image,pdf,word etc
     **/
    public func uploadFileToS3(withKey key : String , contentType type : String, andData data : Data) {
        let awsUploadExp = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
        awsUploadExp.progressBlock = {task ,progress in
            //progress goes here
        }
        guard   let transferUtililty  = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "NAMEOFUTILITY") else{
            return
        }
        let completionHandler : AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock = {(task,error)-> Void in
            //handle your completion
        }

        transferUtililty.uploadData(data, bucket: "YourBucketname", key: key, contentType: type, expression: awsUploadExp, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
   ```